# Horizontal Electrical Outlet - How to Rough?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

I'm out in Chicago, and we are required to pipe in everything with conduit and use metal boxes.

For vertical 2 gang outlets, we use normally a 4 inch box with side mounting to a stud and two mud rings (one for each gang).  Image attached.

[image]

I'm trying to figure out (without ripping apart my house), how all the outlets in my kitchen are horizontal as the mounting flanges I've seen on metal boxes are vertical.

I've used the "old work" boxes with drywall clips and ears to put in a switch or outlet (so you can mount them vertical or horizontal as needed), but when my house was roughed in all of the 1 gang outlets are horizontal.

What sort of metal box is used for rough in that is installed horizontally, like the pictured horizontal outlet?

[image: h]

Comment: Is the mud ring just flipped?

Comment: Those 4x4 boxes are symmetrical, they don't have a vertical or horizontal.  All the mud rings have screw holes

Comment: A 2x4 between studs allows you to rotate the box shown. Easier if the wall is open.

Comment: Is there a horizontal 'stud' (as Jon Custer suggests) - I've seen that used quite frequently to achieve this sort of thing.

Comment: @MikeBrockington -- my Chicago electrician said usually these are vertical in Chicago just based on "how things are done" in our little universe.  So the safe assumption is that it's vertical with a horizontal mud ring, but of course mileage could vary!

Comment: That's they way its done in Chicago. All the receptacles are horizontal and switches are vertical.

Comment: A horizontal stud is called a "dwang" or a "nod" or a "noggin" depending where you're from.  American's walls seem to lack them.

Comment: @Leroy105  I wasn't referring to the main (vertical) studs, but to horizontal spacers used at semi-random intervals. As Criggie says, they have a million and one names, and may not be common where you are. They are also commonly used where a wash-basin is expected or similar significant loads.

Answer (score 7):

### Sideways mud rings

I'm fairly sure that what your installers did to get the horizontal receptacle effect was to take a 4S (4" square) box (or another square box) and then mount a matching 1-gang *mud ring* on the square box so the 1-gang opening in the mud ring is horizontal, not vertical.

[image]

Comment: I was thinking maybe the same thing!  Meanwhile in the rest of the USA, plastic boxes and romex -- unions out in Chicago....  huge pain to do anything electrical.

Comment: @Leroy105 -- well, the initial rough-in's a lot of pipe bending, but think on the bright side, you can swap wires out pretty freely once that pipework's all done :)

Comment: Application: is that I want to change the outlets to have a switch, and then run some electric to the cabinets.  Sounds like we could change the mud ring to a 2'fer and flip things around.

Thinking of doing a outlet + switch (in one gang), but would prefer to convert the box to 2 gang since it's under a wet bar and you need an ice maker and blender right? ;)

Comment: @Leroy105 -- do double check what you have for a box, but what you describe makes sense :)

Comment: Should be easy enough to pull out the outlet and peek into the box to see if this was how it was done.

Comment: Exactly what they did in my kitchen. Made it nice and easy when I went back and added GFCI outlets.+1

Comment: My electrician who is from Chicago, confirmed same thing -- all 4 inch boxes in the house, vertically mounted, and then mud ring one way or the other.  So yes, we're gonna flip some mud rings and run some whips into the cabinets!

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel -- mud rings, do you put in 1/8" taller than finished drywall?

Comment: @Leroy105 They make the mud rings in a variety of heights. I'd aim for flush or no more than 1/16" proud, because if you can get hard flush bottomed-out clean  metal-metal contact between receptacle yoke and mud ring, you don't need a ground wire.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a double outlet box but right side up. Just cut that dry wal out. The double box should cover the hole.

Comment: This won't work for the OP -- they'd have some weird issues with KOs not quite matching up and so on...